# modifying float with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, firefox, html, sticky

I have this code:

```
if(scrollTop < header.orgOffset) {
            document.getElementById('log').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('lista').style.float = 'none';
            document.getElementById('lista').style.marginLeft = 'auto';
            header.element.css('background-color', 'transparent').css('width', '100%').css("box-shadow", "none").css('position', orgCSS.position).css('top','').prev().remove();
            if(i > 0)
                headers[i-1].element.css('z-index', 100);
        }
    }

    //stick headers
    for(i in headers) {
        var header = headers[i];
        //make sure any stuck headers are stuck in the right place(fast scrolling sometimes messes this up)
        if(isStuck(header))
            header.element.css('top','0')

        //skip this header if its bellow the top of the window
        if(scrollTop < header.orgOffset - parseInt(orgCSS.height)) 
            break;

        //if the header is already stuck then ignore it            
        if(!isStuck(header)) {
            if(scrollTop > header.orgOffset) {
                //stick the header
                document.getElementById('log').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('lista').style.float = 'left';
                document.getElementById('lista').style.marginLeft = '20px';
                header.element.css("left", "0px").css("box-shadow", "0 0 5px #000").css('background-color', '#FFF').css('width', '100%').css('position', 'fixed').css('z-index','100').css('top','0').before('<div class=menu> </div>');
                if(i > 0)
                    headers[i-1].element.css('z-index', -1);
```

This works for sticky headers in my page. But modifying the float attribute to left and then back to none doesn't work in firefox. Everything else works fine, and it works fine in chrome, rockmelt and safari.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cssFloat` as the style property instead of `float` for Firefox. You can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float).

Ex

```
document.getElementById('lista').style.cssFloat = 'left';
```